# Response of JSON gem - 1.8.1 downloaded from rubygems.org/gems/json

Tags: ruby, json

I have downloaded the **rubygems.org/gems/json/json-1.8.1.gem** gem to parse a JSON request.

The expected O/P of `JSON.parse(strResponseBody)` method is **"hash of hashes"**.

If we print the output of JSON.parse on following JSON string:

```
   {"BodyStyles":[{"k":"Car"},{"k":"Truck"},{"k":"SUV/Crossover"}]}
```

we get the following output:

```
{"BodyStyles"=>[{"k"=>"Car"}, {"k"=>"Truck"}, {"k"=>"SUV/Crossover"}]}
```

When I execute the following code, I am getting the output as **"hash of Arrays"**:

```
   result.each{|keys,values|
      puts values.class                 ====> Coming as Array.
      values.each{|key,value|
        puts key                        ====> O/P: {"k"=>"Car"} instead of "Car"
      }
      }
```

Anyone has faced this issue??

Please help in getting any work around.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Prasant Sutaria

Answer (score 1):

First of all I am not sure you need to install JSON gem, as I think it has been ported to Ruby all you need to do with Ruby 1.9.3 and above is `require 'json'`, then back to your code

```
{"BodyStyles"=>[{"k"=>"Car"}, {"k"=>"Truck"}, {"k"=>"SUV/Crossover"}]} 

result.each{|keys,values|
  puts values.class                # The key here is "BodyStyles" and the values is an array  
  values.each{|ele|          #since values is an Array ([{"k"=>"Car"}, {"k"=>"Truck"}, {"k"=>"SUV/Crossover"}]) then you should not do "values.each{|key,value|"
    ele.values.first         #It seems you are only interested in the values from the Hash in this case "Car", the assumption here is that you have only one key value mapping, else you might need to use ele.values instead
  }
}
```

There are shorter and more elegant ways to write this, but that depends on you in particular. Take a look at [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) and [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

Answer (score 0):

The result is correct. What you are missing is that the entire Hash is

```
result = {"BodyStyles"=>[{"k"=>"Car"}, {"k"=>"Truck"}, {"k"=>"SUV/Crossover"}]}
```

It means that when you execute

```
result.each { |keys,values| }
```

The each will be executed once (there is only one item in the main Hash) with parameters

```
keys = "BodyStyles" (string)
values = [{"k"=>"Car"}, {"k"=>"Truck"}, {"k"=>"SUV/Crossover"}] (Array)
```

That's the reason why the statement

```
puts values.class
```

prints Array. To achieve the result you want use

```
result["BodyStyles"].each { |items|
  puts items["k"]
}
```